# Spring Boot: Full CRUD REST endpoints are auto-generated and shown in SwaggerUI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, spring-rest

I’ve created a spring-boot project and defined a REST controller with 1 endpoint for `/employers`

```
@RestController
public class EmployerController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployerService employerService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/employers")
    public List<Employer> getEmployers() {
        return (List<Employer>) employerService.getEmployers();
    }
}
```

Additionally, I’ve created the associated EmployerService, EmployerRepository, and Employer entity

When I add Swagger/OpenAPI to the classpath, and then navigate to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`, there is a full CRUD REST definition for the Employer entity which includes `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH`

[image: Full CRUD Rest Definition]

Why is there a full CRUD REST API defined for Employer when I’ve only defined a single endpoint for `GET /employers`? If this is configurable, is it possible to disable the auto-creation of the REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` which I believe would auto expose those crud endpoints once you create an `@Entity` annotated class, and a CrudRepository.

So, what are your spring dependencies in your build.gradle or pom.xml? I would imagine you're using something other than just the usual `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-web` dependencies.

In any case, I don't think all of those those endpoints are coming from the one `@GetMapping` in the snippet you provided. We would have to see the dependencies and the rest of your setup to say for sure. Specifically, what is the `EmployerRepository` implementation extending? If it's a `CrudRepository` and you're using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` I believe that would explain it.

Here are the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/repository-resources.html

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, the Employers repository extends CrudRepository, and I also have `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` in the pom.xml. Thanks for the answer